# How do I update a single value displayed on my website with JS?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

With the help of a realtime firebase database and some arduino code, I am displaying Moisture levels of potting soil on my website. However when the firebase data is updated (every 0.3 seconds), instead of also updating the single value on the website, it adds a new line/print every update. After a short while, my website now looks like this:

`Moisture: 661Moisture: 658Moisture: 660Moisture: 658Moisture: 657`, and it keeps on adding the Moisture: xxx after it with every update. What I want to happen is to just have it displayed once, and push the data so it updates the first value, rather than adding a new one.

I'll leave my code below, how can I go about doing this? It's hard to find things about this on the internet as I am not sure what I am looking for (new to JS).

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.11.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "xx",
    authDomain: "xx",
    databaseURL: "xx",
    projectId: "xx",
    storageBucket: "xx",
    messagingSenderId: "xx",
    appId: "xx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
    

  <script>
    
    var database = firebase.database();

    
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("plant-patrol/Moisture");
    ref.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key; // "plant-patrol"
    var childKey = snapshot.child().key; // "Moisture"
  
    });
  </script>
    
<script>
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.val());
    var snapshotJSON = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());
    var moisture = snapshotJSON;
    moisture = moisture.replace(/[{""}]/g, '');
    moisture = moisture.replace(/[:]/g, ': ');
    document.write(moisture);

  
}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});
    </script>  
  

    
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var div = document.getElementById('moisture');
div.innerHTML = 'Moisture: 55%';
```

```html
<div id='moisture'></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. Could you add some explanation to the code, I am very new to JS so I am not really sure what I am looking at.

Comment: change `document.write(moisture);` for the first code. The first code will find the second one (html) and replace the text inside. `document.write()` adds text to the document instead of replacing it.

Comment: you don't want to use document.write.

Comment: Thank you, with the extra comments and the code I managed to get it to work! :)

Comment: @Luukv19 Hi, welcome in statckoverflow community. in here the way to express gratitude is to mark the answer as accepted as the comments with thanks do not raise the reputation of who give you the solution  while the accepted answers increase his score

Comment: Hello @FrancoRondini I tried doing so, but I am not yet able to give feedback because I do not have 15 reputation myself. I have however marked this answer as accepted. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Hi @Luukv19 just upvoted your question in order to grow your reputation ;-)

Comment: Thank you @FrancoRondini, I can now give reputation! Also upped your responses! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your are using `document.write(moisture)`. This writes the `moisture` variable on the document each time is received.

What you want is to replace a specific text in the document. To do that you must create an element with an unique ID like:

```html
<div id='moisture'></div>
```

First, assing that element to a variable:

```js
var moistureDiv = document.getElementById('moisture');
```

Then, remove the `document.write(moisture)` and add this code to replace the text on the element with "moisture" ID:

```js
moistureDiv.innerHTML = moisture;
```

Comment: Thank you both for including the code and the explanation. I now understand how to tackle these types of problems in the future!